# Redirect to login when the user done with registration

Tags: reactjs, redirect

Redirect, Navigate and redirect don't work for me

I expect to redirect to the login .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76BwK.png)

Comment: please provide [Minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Before routing, u must check if local storage contain auth_token if auth_token is not present, then redirect to login by using history.push("login path") or what are u using please mention some more details about routing package.

```
if(localStorage.getItem(key of that auth_token while setting){
history.push(login route)
}
```

Comment: where is the history(variable) came from?

Comment: from react-router-dom, install react-router-dom and import history 
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';  
and add 
const history = useHistory();

Comment: here the error of this action : export 'useHistory' (imported as 'useHistory') was not found in 'react-router-dom'

Comment: Ok it's because you have installed latest version of react-router-dom  in that case you can  " import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";" and use   
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate("/login"); // /login is path where u want to redirect.

Comment: this action gives me error :

Comment: react-dom.development.js:16227 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: after searching in Google this is the reason of the error --> Having a mismatch between the versions of react and react-dom . Having multiple versions of the react package in the same project. Trying to call a component as a function, -->> How can I solve it?

Comment: Can you share your code snippets in question

Comment: It's ok I used in assync await . Show my sulotion for this

Comment: so is it working fine?

Answer (score 0):

Use the useNavigate in the top of the function. and then ...[Sulotion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pp6no.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).